# How to create a event of type React.FormEvent <HTMLFormElement> React Typescript for tests

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-testing

I have a question about react with tyescript, since as a learning method, I decided to migrate an application made in JavaScript to Typescript, when I got to the tests things got a bit complicated, and if it is not an error, tests pass but my syntax highlighter i.e. tsserver shows me the following:

```
Argument of type '{ preventDefault(): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormEvent<{}>'.    Type '{ preventDefault(): void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FormEvent<{}>': nativeEvent, currentTarget, target, bubbles, and 10 more.
```

The code that is inside the test is the following:

```
        const wrapper = mount(
          <MyScreen />
        );

        wrapper.find( 'input' ).simulate( 'change', {
            target: {
                name: "myInputText",
                value: "This is a test",
            },
        });

        wrapper.find( 'form' ).prop( 'onSubmit' )({
            preventDefualt(){},
        });
```

**I had a doubt why I don't want it to have any syntax highlighting that says that**

Image of how it looks in my nvim code editor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4OWX.png)